# cp command should ignore some files

Tags: shell, command-line

Sometimes I need to perform  following command

```
cp -rv demo demo_bkp
```

However I want to ignore all the files in directory .git . How do I achieve that? It takes a long time to copy .git files and I do not need those files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy folder recursively, excluding some folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193584/copy-folder-recursively-excluding-some-folders)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

To ignore a git directory specifically, I'd [try `git export`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export) first.

But in general, to copy a directory tree excluding certain files or folders, I'd recommend using `rsync` instead of `cp`. The syntax is mostly the same, but `rsync` has *way* more options, including one to exclude selected files:

```
rsync -lrv --exclude=.git demo demo_bkp
```

See e.g. [the man page](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) for more info.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there are other options that would have prevented this,  or it's something to do with Linux versions but if I follow your example I get `demo` as a subdirectory of `demo_bkp`. However, using `rsync -rv --exclude=.git demo/ demo_bkp` creates a new directory that contains all of the files from the first directory.

Comment: So far, how to `cp` while excluding git is exactly what i am looking for! I do not want to use rsync in my scripts. Wouldn't be better to advise `tar` instead? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2193806/2494754

Comment: @Cryptopat For this question, no, it wouldn't be better to advise `tar` instead (IMO) because `rsync` is a superior option. It's specifically designed for this task and the usage is more straightforward. If you don't want to use `rsync`, I suggest one of two things: (1) Try one of the solutions recommended in the other answers to this question. That's part of why there are multiple answers. Or (2) post a separate followup question asking how to do this copy without using `rsync`, and including any other constraints you may have.

Comment: sync is not a copy. It is creating links from the new folder to the old one. Any changes in the old folder will be reflected in the new one. this  is not a copy.

Comment: @zwitterion's comment is not correct. `rsync` (not `sync`, which is a tool to flush write buffers) does not create links, but instead copies the files. Changes to the old folder will not be reflected in the new folder (unless `rsync` is run again, obviously)

Comment: Why do you recommend using the “l" flag and the “r" flag (instead of “a” flag)?

Comment: It's to match the behavior of `cp -r` as closely as possible. Specifically, `cp -r` copies regular files, directories, and links (which `rsync` without `-l` does not), but does not copy over attributes like permissions and modification times (which `rsync -a` does).

Answer (score 11):

OK. Brace yourself. This isn't pretty.

```
find demo -depth -name .git -prune -o -print0 | cpio -0pdv --quiet demo_bkp
```

What's going on here?

1. `find demo | cpio -p demo_bkp` finds files matching whatever criteria you want and uses cpio to copy them (so-called "pass-through" mode).
2. `find -depth` changes the order the files are printed in to match the order cpio wants.
3. `find -name .git -prune` tells find not to recurse down `.git` directories.
4. `find -print0 | cpio -0` has find use NUL characters (`\0`) to separate file names. This is for maximum robustness in case there are any weirdly-named files with spaces, newlines, or other unusual characters.
5. `cpio -d` creates directories as needed.
6. `cpio -v --quiet` prints each file name while omitting the "X blocks copied" message cpio normally prints at the end.

Answer (score 5):

I think this will do the trick:

```
cd demo
find . -not -path \*/.\* -type d -exec mkdir -p -- ../demo_bkp/{} \;
find . -not -path \*/.\* -type f -exec cp -- {} ../demo_bkp/{} \;
```

First finds and creates each directory. Then finds and copies each file.

Note it will not work with special files (symbolic links, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Continuing on the `rsync` idea, if you have so many file patterns to ignore, you can use the `--exclude-from=FILE` option.

The `--exclude-from=FILE` option takes a file [`FILE`] that contains exclude patterns (one pattern per line) and excludes all the files matching the patterns.

So, say you want to copy a directory `demo` to `demo_bkp`, but you want to ignore files with the patterns - `.env`, `.git`, `coverage`, `node_modules`. You can create a file called `.copyignore` and add the patterns line by line to `.copyignore`:

```sh
.env
.git
coverage
node_modules
```

Then run:

```sh
rsync -rv --exclude-from=./.copyignore demo demo_bkp
```

That's it. `demo` would be copied into `demo_bkp` with all the files matching the patterns specified in `.copyignore` ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, possibly best runtime, conforming to OP (who wants to use `cp`):

```
touch /path/to/target/.git
cp -n -ax * /path/to/target/
rm /path/to/target/.git
```

This exploits the `-n` option of `cp`, which forces `cp` to not overwrite existing targets.

Drawback: Works with GNU `cp`. If you don't have GNU `cp`, then the `cp` operation might return an error code (`1`), which is annoying because then you can't tell if it was a real failure.