# Pull git contents without the meta content

Tags: git

Example:
Git Repository abc.git contains tracked files abc-home.txt and abc-artifact.img

When I do git clone I get the files and git creates a .git directory with the meta information.
Can I ask git to give me just the files without the meta information?

clarification Edit: I'm pulling from a remote bare repo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cp command should ignore some files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672480/cp-command-should-ignore-some-files)

Comment: @rajuGT No, that's definitely not a duplicate of the question you suggested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

Comment: @fir3x Please consider marking some answer as an accepted answer, so others can more easily find a help, if this question won't be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git archive` and extract it immediately using `tar`:

`git archive <branch-name> | tar -xC ./extract-here`

Or if you're fine with an archive, you can create a zip of your repository:

`git archive --format zip --output <repository.zip> <branch-name>`

If you don't have a clone of repository locally, just add option `--remote=<repository-url>` to the `git archive` command.