# Copy .git folder terminal with copy all

Tags: git, macos, recursion, cp

I'm trying to use `cp` to copy all files from sub-folder to current folder in zsh on osx. I basically want to have the problem these people are trying to get around:

- [cp command should ignore some files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672480/cp-command-should-ignore-some-files)
- [How to use 'cp' command to exclude a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585929/how-to-use-cp-command-to-exclude-a-specific-directory)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91022/copy-all-dotfiles-except-for-git-and

I want the *opposite*.
When I copy files, my `.git` folder is NOT being copied along with the rest of the files.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
cp -RLv fetch/* ./
cp -RL fetch/* ./
cp -Rv fetch/* ./
cp -R fetch/* ./
cp -rv fetch/* ./
cp -r fetch/* ./
cp fetch/* ./
```

Is this possible? I'm okay with using `mv` too if I have to.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/61611/219423

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct command is `cp -r fetch/. ./`

Asterisk (`*`) doesn't work because it is extended by the shell, and by default it doesn't include dotfiles/directories.

Answer (score 1):

try this?

`cp -a fetch fetch-copy`

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux system:

```
cp -rT fetch .
```

I believe on BSD this would work:

```
cp -R fetch/ .
```