# cp dir recursivly excluding 2 subdirs

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cp

I have 1 directory with 9 subdirectories and 10 files.
Subdirectory have next level subdirectories and files.

```
/home/directory/
/home/directory/subdirectory1
/home/directory/subdirectory2
...
/home/directory/subdirectory9
/home/directory/file1
...
/home/directory/file10
```

I want to copy all subdirectories and files recursivly excluding:

```
/home/directory/subdirectory5
/home/directory/subdirectory7
```

What is the best way for it?

Comment: first copy complete folder recursively,then use rm command to remove subfolders 5 & 7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy folder recursively, excluding some folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193584/copy-folder-recursively-excluding-some-folders)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the `find` command will help you:

```
$ find /home/directory -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'subdirectory[57]' -or -exec cp -r {} /path/to/dir \;
```

Comment: this doesn't preserve the directory tree structure, @kjohri 's answer with rsync is much better

Comment: this command is not even working for me, it says -exec is missing a parameter

Answer (score 30):

```
rsync -avz --exclude subdirectory5 --exclude subdirectory7 /home/directory/ target-path
```

Comment: rsync is the way to go. forget about cp

Answer (score 11):

I don't know a good way of doing it with `cp`, but it's fairly easy using `rsync` and the `--exclude` switch.

Answer (score 2):

use `rsync` with `--exclude` is better

Comment: rsync is a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--exclude` option of `tar`:

```
{ cd /home/directory; tar -c --exclude=subdirectory5 --exclude=subdirectory7 .; } | { cd _destination_ ; tar -x; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Kev's way is better, but this would also work:

```
find "/home/folder" -maxdepth 1 | sed -e "/^\/home\/folder$/d" -e "/^\/home\/folder\/subfolder5$/d" -e "/^\/home\/folder\/subfolder7$/d" -e "s/^/cp \-r /" -e  "s/$/ \/home\/target/" | cat
```

Explained :

```
find "/home/folder" -maxdepth 1 |
// get all files and dirs under /home/folder, pipe output

sed -e "/^\/home\/folder$/d" 
// have sed strip the path being searched, or the cp -r we prepend later will pickup the excluded dirs again.

-e "/^\/home\/folder\/subfolder5$/d"
// have sed strip subfolder5

-e "/^\/home\/folder\/subfolder7$/d"
// have sed strip subfolder7

-e "s/^/cp \-r /"
// have sed prepend "cp -r " to each line

-e  "s/$/ \/home\/target/" | cat
// have sed append targetdir to each line.
```

Outputs:

```
cp -r /home/folder/subfolder9 /home/target
cp -r /home/folder/subfolder1 /home/target
cp -r /home/folder/file10 /home/target
cp -r /home/folder/subfolder2 /home/target
cp -r /home/folder/file1 /home/target
cp -r /home/folder/subfolder3 /home/target
```

Change `| cat` to `| sh` to execute the command.

<A big disclaimer goes here>

You should Kev's solution is better

Comment: +1 for overcomplicated sed piped to cat or sh- best way to build other complex scripts. +1 for Kev's right answer in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the `cp` command like this:

```
cp -r /home/directory/!(subdirectory5|subdirectory7) /destination
```

Comment: Not working in bash! the output is "bash: !: event not found"

Comment: In this case you should set call: **shopt -s extglob** and **mkdir destination**. Then it will work.