# How to copy selective folders into a different directory

Tags: unix

```
folderA contains [dirA, dirB, dirC, fileA, fileB]
```

I want to copy `folderA to folderA-copy without dirB and dirC` how should I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193584/copy-folder-recursively-excluding-some-folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rsync command exclude option which provides you with option to enter regex for folder/files or specify a file containing all the directories you want to ignore or specify particular directory or file.