# git export plus non-commited files

Tags: git, git-archive

I want to copy a folder in a git repository to make a new repository (If you need to know why, I created a rails project one folder below git root, and Heroku really dislikes this).

I did a git-archive step as suggested on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/160608/170521). However there are several files that are un-commited that were not moved by the git-archive step.

Any suggestions to quickly copy the uncommited files to the exported folder? Even a way to list uncommited files could work, so I can go an use that to copy them with some script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try copying all directories/files in your folder except for the `.git` directory. See option 1 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223842/git-copy-newest-branch-to-another-directory/18223900#18223900) to [GIT - copy newest branch to another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223842/git-copy-newest-branch-to-another-directory).