# Linux: How to copy recursively omitting certain folder?

Tags: linux, bash, copy, cp

Example:

```
dir1  
|_ filea  
|_ fileb  
|_ foldera  
   |_ filez  
|_ folderxy  
   |_ filexy
```

I want to copy `dir1` with `cp -r dir1 desti/nation` but omitting `folderxy`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use the `--exclude` option to `rsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rsync. If you have a lot of stuff to exclude you can create a file and pass it in as `--exclude-from=filename`. Look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193584/copy-folder-recursively-excluding-some-folders).

```
rsync -av --exclude='path1' --exclude='path2' source destination
```