# Copy folder excluding in bash file does not excluding so many files

Tags: bash

This is my code to exclude some files,when copy files from one folder to another folder,[Copy folder recursively, excluding some folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193584/copy-folder-recursively-excluding-some-folders) , I got the idea from this link.

But now the problem is,if I need to exclude only one file,this is working,but for many it's not.(I include all the files,that need to exclude in a text file and give the name of that text file like this,exclude=textfile.txt ,but still it's not working)

```
cd /source_directory
tar cf - --exclude=dir_to_exclude . | (cd /destination && tar xvf - )
```

Comment: Why "copy" when you `tar` in fact?

Comment: actually,I got this code from that link,I just need to copy folder by excluding some folders

Comment: Why not use the first solution? RSync with a file?

Comment: for reasync i need to install something,i'm doing this bash file for a user,so I can't expect them to install those

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution,here when I use `exclude-from`,then I can able to exclude so many files or folders.

```
cd /source_directory
tar cf - --exclude-from=dir_to_exclude . | (cd /destination && tar xvf - )
```