# Prevent CP hardlink by copying files into subfolder

Tags: bash, unix

I have a folder structure like this

```
a/
-b/
-c.txt
-d.txt
-backups/
```

I want to move the contents of folder `a` into `backups` so the folder structure is this.

```
a/
-b/
-c.txt
-d.txt
-backups/
    -b/
    -c.txt
    -d.txt
```

Here are the commands I have used so far.

```
for d in a/*/ ; do
    mkdir -p ${d}backups/
    cp -ra ${d}* backups
done
```

I make the folder backups then I try to copy the content into the `backups` folder. However, I get the error: CP Hardlink cannot copy folder onto itself. How can i do this?

Thank You

Comment: See: [Copy folder recursively, excluding some folders](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2193584/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a
├── b
├── backups
├── c.txt
└── d.txt

2 directories, 2 files
```

Enable [extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob)
 by `shopt -s extglob` and execute `cp -r !(backups/) backups`. The following will be the result:

```
a
├── b
├── backups
│   ├── b
│   ├── c.txt
│   └── d.txt
├── c.txt
└── d.txt

3 directories, 4 files
```

Comment: Yea I wasnt aware of extglob before but its pretty damn cool! Nice for a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

it is trying to copy "backups" into "backups" , so you need to make sure you exclude "backups" from the a/*/ pattern.

you should probably use "find" to find files with a given pattern and exclude the "backup" directory. With find you can do "-not -name backup"

Comment: i know rsync can exclude files but how would I do that in the pattern?