# How to exclude node_modules during backup

Tags: bash, macos

Is it possible to exclude node_modules when backing up files to an external HD?

I'm wondering if there is a **flag** that I could pass on the terminal to copy all files but **node_modules from my machine to an external HD**. Something like a .gitignore before pushing code to a remote repo for instance.

I'm using a mac.

Comment: You might check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193584/copy-folder-recursively-excluding-some-folders?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thank you Sean. will check it out.